# Problem regarding many to many relationship between Post and tags (post_tag as join table)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I been building my blogging website using rails and react. I encountered a problem when I update my posts with new tags.
This is how my interface looks like:

[image]

When I add a new tag "test" into my update form, it is expected to result in "work" and "test" tags. However, it becomes like this:

[image]

Instead of adding only "test" tag onto the list, it added both "work" and "test" tags same time and now there's duplication in my tags. In my backend, it becomes like this:

[image]

There are two separate "test" tags with different ids. What I want to achieve is to create tags but not duplicate same tags so that I can add filter posts based on their tags. Right now I can't do that. I have provided my codes so please help.

**Frontend (React)**

```
***This is my Profile.jsx (It holds multiple postContainers.jsx using .map method):***

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import PostContainer from './PostContainers'

export default function Profile({currentUser}){

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    
    function updatePost(postObj){
        const newPostArray = posts.map((post) => {
            if(post.id === postObj.id){
                return postObj
            }
            return post
        })
        setPosts(newPostArray)
    }
    
    function deletePost(postId){
        const newArray = posts.filter(post => post.id !== postId)
        setPosts(newArray)
    }

    const getPosts = () => {
        fetch(`/post/${currentUser.id}`)
        .then((r) =>{
          if(r.ok){
              r.json().then((posts)=>setPosts(posts))
          }
      })
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getPosts()
    }, [])

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello {currentUser.username}</h1>
            <h3>What's on your mind today?</h3>
            <div className='postWrapper'>
                <h2>Your Posts</h2>
                <div className='postLists'>
                    {posts && posts?.map((post)=>
                        <PostContainer  key={post.id} post={post} updatePost={updatePost} deletePost={deletePost} />
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

***This is my postContainer.jsx (It represents individual white cards)***

```
 import { useState } from 'react';

export default function PostContainer({ post, updatePost, deletePost }){
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
    const [title, setNewTitle] = useState("");
    const [content, setNewContent] = useState("");
    const [tags, setNewTags] = useState('');
    const userId = post.user_id;


    function handleDelete(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(post.id)
        fetch(`/post/${post.id}`,{
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
        })
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then(deletePost(post.id))
    }

    // Send patch requests
    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Check the tags if they are deleted properly.
        const patchedPost = {
            title,
            content,
            userId,
            tags_attributes: tags.split(',').map((el) => { return {name: el} })
        }

        fetch(`/post/${post.id}`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(patchedPost)
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(x => updatePost(x))
        .catch(err => alert(err.message))
        setIsShown(false);
    }
 
    // Display update component
    const handleUpdate = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsShown(current => !current)
        // Preload the information using the set states.
        // setTitle, setContent, setTags.
        setNewTitle(post.title);
        setNewContent(post.content);
        setNewTags(post.tags.map((x)=>x.name));
    }

    return(
    <div>
        <div>
        {isShown && (
            <div>
                <form className='update-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Title</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text' value={title} onChange={(e)=>setNewTitle(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <label>Content</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text' value={content} onChange={(e)=>setNewContent(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <label>Tags</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text' value={tags} onChange={(e)=>setNewTags(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <button type='submit'>Update</button>
                    <button onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); setIsShown(false)}}>Cancel</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )}
        </div><br/>
        <div className='postContainer'>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p className="users-posts-content">{post.content}</p>
            <p>Tags: {post.tags.map((x)=> x.name).join(',')}</p>
            <button onClick={(e)=>handleUpdate(e)}>Update</button> 
            <button onClick={(e)=>handleDelete(e)}>Delete Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

***This is my Post.Jsx (It contains a form to create a new post and not shown on the images)***

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Post({currentUser}){
    const[title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const[content, setContent] = useState("");
    const[tags, setTags] = useState("");
    const user_id = currentUser.id
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();       
        const newPost = {
            title,
            content,
            user_id,
            tags_attributes: tags.split(',').map((el) => { return {name: el} })
        }

        //It checks if all the values are entered before posting.
        if(title === "" || content === "" || user_id === "" || tags === ""){
            alert("Please enter all the inputs!")
        }else(
            fetch(`/post`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {"Content-Type": 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(newPost),   
            }).then((r) =>{
                if (r.ok){
                    r.json().then(navigate('/profile'))
                    alert("New post created!")
                }else{
                    alert("New post creation failed")
                }
            })
        )
        
    }
    return(
        <div className="post-form-container">
            <form className="post-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Title</label><br/>
                <input 
                    className='title-input' 
                    type='text' 
                    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}  
                    value={title}>
                </input><br/>

                <label>Content</label><br/>
                <textarea 
                    className="content-input" 
                    type='text' 
                    onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}  
                    value={content} 
                    placeholder="Start typing~">
                </textarea><br/>

                <label>Tags: seperated by commas</label><br/>
                <input 
                    className="tags-input" 
                    type='text' 
                    onChange={(e) => setTags(e.target.value)} 
                    value={tags}>
                </input><br/>   

                <button className="post-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Backend (Ruby on Rails)**
**This is my post_controller.rb (Contains methods for creating, updating, and deleting posts)**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorized
    skip_before_action :authorized, only: [:index, :show, :create]
    

    def show
        posts = User.find(params[:id]).posts
        render json: posts, include: :User
    end

    def index      
        posts = Post.all
        render json: posts, include: :User
    end

    def create      
        user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        post = user.posts.create(post_params)
        if post.valid?
            render json: post, status: :created
        else
            render json: {error: post.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
    
    def update      
        post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if post
            # Before update we have to compare two arrays and delete any tags that are not found in posts.tags
            # Iterate over posts. 
            post.update(post_params)
            render json: post, status: :accepted
        else
            render json: {error: "Post not found"}, status: :not_found
        end
    end

    def destroy
        post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if post
            post.destroy
            
            render json: {}
        else
            render json: {error: "post not found"}, status: :not_found
        end
    end

    private

    def authorize
        return render json: { error: "Not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized unless session.include? :user_id
    end

    def post_params
        # params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, tags_attributes: [:name])
        params.permit(:title, :content, tags_attributes: [:name])
    end 
end
```

**This is my Post.rb model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :post_tags, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tags, through: :post_tags

    # Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```

**This is my tag.rb model**

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :post_tags
    has_many :posts, through: :post_tags
    
end
```

**Lastly, this is my post_tags.rb model (join table)**

```
class PostTag < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :tag
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the id field of persisted record from the form in order to tell rails that this object already in the db.

```
def post_params
  params.permit(:title, :content, tags_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

Also if you want user to have ability to remove tags you can modify your code like this.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :post_tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and in your controller:

```
def post_params
  params.permit(:title, :content, tags_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
end
```

when the user want to delete any tag from post add `_destroy` parameter as '1' along with the id in the fields of that tag

Comment: It still doesn't work. It keeps creating duplicated tags.

Comment: can you share the params you got on update request?

Comment: params.permit(:title, :content, tags_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])

Comment: no i mean the parameters you got when you make a request from react.

Comment: {id: 3, title: 'test 3', content: 'test 3', tags: Array(3), user_id: 1, …}
content: "test 3"
id: 3
tags: Array(3)
0: {id: 7, name: 'test', created_at: '2022-07-07T22:57:51.302Z', updated_at: '2022-07-07T22:57:51.302Z'}
1: {id: 9, name: 'test', created_at: '2022-07-07T23:31:10.812Z', updated_at: '2022-07-07T23:31:10.812Z'}
2: {id: 10, name: 'life', created_at: '2022-07-07T23:31:10.815Z', updated_at: '2022-07-07T23:31:10.815Z'}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
title: "test 3"
Is this what you want to see?

Comment: no, this is the response from rails server right? i need to see the post request params that you sent from the react app to rails server.